# What is the Apache equivalent of nginx's try_files directive

Tags: apache, nginx, server, configuration, vhosts

Please help, i'm new to server configuration.

I'm trying to write the equivalent of the nginx server configuration below in Apache's virtual host configuration.

```
server {

    root /path/to/public/root/directory;
    server_name myservername.test;

    location /api {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /web {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
    }

}
```

From what i have researched, I tried to do the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myservername.test
        DocumentRoot "/path/to/public/root/directory"

        <Directory /path/to/public/root/directory/>
                RewriteEngine on
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} "=/web" [OR]    
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} "=/api"

                RewriteRule . index.php [QSA, L]
        </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myservername.test
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

but it did not work. I have tweaked the code from top to bottom but my apache server keeps throwing errors.
My Apache version is 2.4.52

Note: It is neccessary i do this in apache's vhost and not in the .htaccess file

Please help. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work.

The first mistake i made was forgetting to enable `mod_rewrite`, `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http`.

second mistake was i created two vhost with the same `ServerName` value, apache seems to ignore one of them

After enabling those apache modules,  here is the final result that worked for me

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myservername.test
    #
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "=/web" [OR]    
    RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "=/api"
    RewriteRule . index.php [QSA]
    #
    ProxyPass "/"  "http://localhost:80/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/"  "http://localhost:80/"
</VirtualHost>
```